# How to add SIP Trunk on Kamailio?

Tags: routes, sip, kamailio, trunk

I have this case:

My Kamailio ip is 10.12.13.0 with domain example.com. I have create user account only 1 (ex: Anna). With SIP Client i have register and i want to call Anthony with same domain but in different ip 10.12.13.1. So the INVITE will be Anna@example.com (10.12.13.0) to Anthony@example.com (10.12.13.1)

I have try this case with Minisipserver and the configuration is more easy. Just add SIP Trunk, add Prefix, add AnalyzeCalledNumber. For Kamailio i dont get any tutuorial. Can anyone give tutorial. Im sorry if the title is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kamailio isn't a PBX or a Softswitch, it's a toolbox to make SIP stuff.

You have to tell Kamailio what to do with the INVITE using the config file. This means you have to store the details for Anna and Anthony so when Kamailio receives the INVITE for Anthony@example.com from Anna, Kamailio can lookup Anthony's IP Address and forward the SIP invite to Anthony's IP address.

I wrote a primer with the [basics of how to use Kamailio called Kamailio 101](https://nickvsnetworking.com/kamailio-introduction/) - which may be of some use to help get you started. The tutorial goes through how to take registrations and calling from one registered user to another.

Kamailio is awesome, hugely scaleable and very flexible, but it may not be as easy as FreeSWITCH or Asterisk when it comes to getting something basic working quickly without much of a background in SIP signaling.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for the explanation. I think i get what i need from your article